# Fetch is working via Postman not from React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post

I have created API in Node JS express. Fetch call to this API is working via Postman. When it is called via React, It is not working. Body is empty and Response is also empty.

node js: Backend

````
router.post('/signup',async (req, res) =>{
    const useremail = req.body.email;
    const pass = req.body.password;
    console.log('pass 1:' , req.body);
    
    var username = req.body.user;```



  Front end:
const data = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/signup',
            {
             method: "POST",
             mode:"no-cors",
             headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
               },
               body: JSON.stringify({ email:'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com' })

            }
            ).then((response) => {
              console.log(response);
              if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
              }
              throw new Error('Something went wrong');
            })
            .then((responseJson) => {
}
````

Printed the Request in backend:

```
pass 1: {}
in Error before CreateUser FirebaseAuthError: The email address is improperly formatted.
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/suku/Documents/GitHub/Bunty-Sales/src/Frontend/src/backend/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
    at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/suku/Documents/GitHub/Bunty-Sales/src/Frontend/src/backend/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (/Users/suku/Documents/GitHub/Bunty-Sales/src/Frontend/src/backend/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:149:16)
    at AuthRequestHandler.AbstractAuthRequestHandler.getAccountInfoByEmail (/Users/suku/Documents/GitHub/Bunty-Sales/src/Frontend/src/backend/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:935:35)
    at Auth.BaseAuth.getUserByEmail (/Users/suku/Documents/GitHub/Bunty-Sales/src/Frontend/src/backend/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/base-auth.js:157:40)
    at /Users/suku/Documents/GitHub/Bunty-Sales/src/Frontend/src/backend/routes/handler.js:78:4
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/suku/Documents/GitHub/Bunty-Sales/src/Frontend/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/suku/Documents/GitHub/Bunty-Sales/src/Frontend/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/suku/Documents/GitHub/Bunty-Sales/src/Frontend/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/suku/Documents/GitHub/Bunty-Sales/src/Frontend/src/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) {
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'auth/invalid-email',
    message: 'The email address is improperly formatted.'
  },
  codePrefix: 'auth'
}
in Error before generateEmailVerificationLink
error 1:Error: The email address is improperly formatted.
```

Comment: `Error before CreateUser FirebaseAuthError: The email address is improperly formatted.` is the backend. Without firing a request from the UI, you cant say `fetch` is not working.

Comment: @mchowdam I triggered the request via UI. Body is always empty. and Res.End is also not returning any value back to frontend(React)